# Google+ API Login working only on mobile devices

Tags: google-plus

I am using a wordpress plugin WSL (wordpress social plugin) to add social login buttons to my login form. I have connected google client ID to the settings and I believe the settings are correct.

The problem is the following. If I test Google+ login on mobile device it works. I tested it on an android phone using chrome and on IPhone (safari and chrome) and it works as intended. After authenication the following picture appears, and after choosing either option I get redirected and logged in.

[Procedure that is missing on desktop and shows on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QDpn.png)

If I try this on any device largr than a mobile phone, the screen seen on the image above doesn`t show up at all and the authenication popup is closed and nothing happens, leaving the form with "connect with G+" still opened. So basically on desktop I get to the part of choosing google account but then the popup closes and nothing happens. And this in only on desktop devices.

Does anyone have a clue, what might be causing that? Is it possible that my wordpress theme is blocking something? I tried literally everything. And the browser console and PHP error log are free of errors. I dont know how to debug this problem...

Thank you in advance for any thougts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Under the "widgets" tab of the plugin settings I had to change the Authentication display to "in page" rather than "popup". Now It works!